# How to create a dictionary value for each given key?

Tags: python

I have a list `l=['a','b','c']` and I want to create a dict that takes these items as keys and then adds a value to it. Such as:

```
d={ 'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2 }
```

How would I be able to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to create this dictionary. Here is just a few:

```
>>> dc = dict(zip(ls, range(3))) 
>>> dc2 = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(ls)}
>>> dc2
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}

>>> assert dc == dc2
>>>       # silence because they're same
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
l=['a','b','c']

d = dict(zip(l,range(len(l))))

print(d)  # {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```py
l = ['a','b','c']
d = {element:index for index,element in enumerate(l)}
```

which will give you each element mapped to its index.

if you want to set some arbitrary value, use

```py
l = ['a','b','c']
d = {element:value for element in l}
```